# Finding a value from gridview based on text specified in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, grid

I have binded a gridview with data and a textbox in c# code
Now based on a textbox text I need to search whether the data exists in the whole gridview. If the data exists then continue or else no data found should be displayed
I want if the data is matched the loop should stop and exit and if data not found display the error.

[Image of gridview and textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d0P3.png)

I have tried this code but does not work

```
function itemvalidate()
{
    var gv = document.getElementById("<%=griditemdetails.ClientID %>");
    var txtItmCode = document.getElementById('<%= txtitemcode.ClientID %>').value;
    var gvRowCount = gv.rows.length;
    var i = 1;
    for (i; i <= gvRowCount; i++)
    {

        var LblVal = gv.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[1].innerHTML;
        alert(txtItmCode);
        alert(LblVal);
        if (txtItmCode == LblVal)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Item not found');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)) / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: @Hille code i have tried

Comment: Please add more Information, like what error do you get or what do you think the error is or why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Hille the code works but the loop should search values from grid specified in textbox and if the value matches it should stop and exit and if the value from textbox is not found in gridview the error message should be displayed

Comment: Then point that out instead of `I have tried this code but does not work`

Comment: the loop executes but when the data is not matched with lblval it gives item not found even if the data exists in the gridview @Hille

Comment: Then [edit] your question with that explanation... It's not that difficult. For more help read our [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.